# I get error 13 type mismatch vba when run another micro

Tags: excel, vba

I have to macro 
one for changing the text in rang to uppercase and the other one for clear rang content.
This the first one

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not (Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B9:B28")) _
  Is Nothing) Then
    With Target
        If Not .HasFormula Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            .Value = UCase(.Value)
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

It work fine and when I enter a value it changes it to uppercase, But when I run this macro to clear range content

```
Sub clearCellContentsKeepFormatting()
    Dim Answer As VbMsgBoxResult
    Answer = MsgBox("Are you sure about this?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Clear All Proudcts")

    If Answer = vbYes Then
        Range("B9", "B28").ClearContents
        Range("C9", "C28").ClearContents
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

I get

> Runtime Error 13 type mismatch

And when I press debug button it marks this line

```
.Value = UCase(.Value)
```

So, How can I fix that?

Comment: You can't do that to multiple cells in one go so either add a check in your change event that `target.count=1` or disable events in your clearcell procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening because .Value is an array if the target range has more than one cell, and you cant call `UCase` on an array.

You could get round this by processing each cell one at a time:

```
Dim c As Range
With Target
    If Not .HasFormula Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each c In Target
            c.Value = UCase(c.Value)
        Next c
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End With
```

though this will have a performance impact.

Another point is that you appear to be attempting to set the whole of the Target range to upper case, not only the part that overlaps with B9:B28.  If you only want B9:B28 to be forced to upper case, you need something like:

```
Dim rngIntersection As Range
Set rngIntersection = Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B9:B28"))

If Not (rngIntersection Is Nothing) Then
    Dim c As Range
    With rngIntersection
       If Not .HasFormula Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            For Each c In rngIntersection
                c.Value = UCase(c.Value)
            Next c
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End With
End If
```

Comment: I replaced my old code by yours but it did not work, I don't know if I do that in the right way, because I don't have a big knowledge with VBA.

Comment: @HusinAljawad - "did not work" isn't much to go on.  I suggest you update your question with your modified code.

Comment: @HusinAljawad - One possibility is that a previous failed run with your original code left `Application.EnableEvents` set to False.  In which case you could try closing and restarting Excel before running the macro.